# jQuery: Detach and Append at the same time

Tags: jquery

I have 2 menus. I want to display the menu1 when the screen size is < 500px and the menu2 when the screen size is > 500px.
Also, I HAVE to use the detach() function and not functions like hide().

Here's my code:

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if ( $("body").outerWidth() < 500) {
      $(".menu1").detach();
      $(".action-menu2").append($(".menu2"));
    }
    else {
      $(".menu2").detach();
      $(".action-menu1").append($(".menu1"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  
  <div class="action-menu1">
    <p class="menu1">menu1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="action-menu2">
    <p class="menu2">menu2</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: You need to store it into a variable like the example https://api.jquery.com/detach/ follow that pattern.

Comment: The thing is : i have a detach() and an append() in the if and in the else, so this solution doesn't cover all the problem...

Comment: It is part of the solution.... You need to code it for one and then reverse it for the other.... So start with showing hiding one. After you get that work, add in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation here: [jQuery detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) you have to assign the detached element in a variable for being able to reinsert it into the DOM later.

Your code will become something like:

```
var menu1,
    menu2;

$(window).on('load', function(){
    menu1 = $(".menu1");
    menu2 = $(".menu2");
});

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if ( $("body").outerWidth() < 500) {
      if( menu1 ) {
          $(".menu1").remove();
      } else {
          menu1 = $(".menu1").detach();
      }
      $(".action-menu2").append(menu2);
    }
    else {

      if( menu2  ) {
          $(".menu2").remove();
      } else {
          menu2 = $(".menu2").detach();
      }

      $(".action-menu1").append(menu1);
    }
});
```

I did not test this code, but I guess it should work. I know it can be done better, but at least it gives you a head start

Comment: Why do you have remove?

Comment: in case menu2 is already defined it no longer needs to be detached. It can just be removed. Same with menu 1. `remove()` is a bit "cheaper" than `detach()` as far as I know